# Center of gravity of a cylinder in 3D space

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

am trying to find the center of gravity coordinates of a cylinder(x,y,z coordinates). however,I cannot figure it out using the triple integral method especially when it comes to the integral bounds. Is there a way of getting the bounds easily? Or is there a general formula of finding those coordinates? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Answer (score 3):

Using *Mathematica*'s region functionality, you can get the centroid like this:

```
cyl=Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1];
RegionCentroid[cyl];
(* {0, 0, 1/2} *)
```

Please have a look at the Wolfram-documentation for further details:

- [RegionCentroid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionCentroid.html)
- [Cylinder](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cylinder.html)

### Howto calculate the center of gravity yourself

Since a cylinder is symmetrical around the center axis, the centroid is always halfway through this axis:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}x_c\\y_c\\z_c\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{array}\right)+\frac1 2\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1-x_0\\y_1-y_0\\z_1-z_0\end{array}\right)$$